# Using jquery to capture event and ajax call back

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do something simple, capture any click event and send the url to a php script.

With the `alert(a);` the `ajax.php` will be call every single time, if I remove it, once every 20 clicks will work, I wonder if it's because the `alert(a)` slow things down ?

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var a = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax.php",
        data: { b1: a , b2: "456" },

    });
    alert(a);
});
```

Comment: what is your question here

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ukd2X/

Comment: As far as i can see, the `/ajax.php` will get called for every click, irrespective of the `alert`

Comment: My issue / question is that it does not

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the A, there is still the event to go to another page. So do this:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var a = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax.php",
        data: { b1: a , b2: "456" },
        success : function(){
            document.location = a;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If I add e.preventDefault(); then it will load ajax.php but not follow the link.